# A question on counting processes

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Here is a question on counting processes. Could anyone try on it? :)

Let $\{X(t):t>0\}$ be a random process obtained by switching between the values $0$ and $1$ according to the event times in a counting process $\{N(t):t>0\}$. Let $P(X(0)=0)=p$ and

\begin{align}
P(N(t)=k)=\frac{1}{1+\mu t}\left(\frac{\mu t}{1+\mu t}\right)^k 
\end{align}

for $k=0,1,\ldots$. Find the pmf of $X(t)$.

Comment: You just wrote the pmf of $X(t)$... do you mean $P(N(t)=k)=\frac{1}{1+\mu t}\bigg(\frac{\mu t}{1+ \mu t}\bigg)^k$ ?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I updated it.

Comment: Let me just make sure I'm understanding this problem correctly. Suppose $T_1,T_2,T_3,\ldots$ are the arrival times in this counting process. What you're saying is that, if you begin at $X(0)=0$, then $X(t)=0$ for any $t\in [0,T_1)$, $X(t)=1$ for any $t\in [T_1,T_2)$, $X(t)=0$ for any $t\in [T_2,T_3)$, etc... ?

Comment: sorry that I actually was confused about how $X(t)$ and $N(t)$ are related.  Your explanation gave me some clue on it. But then $X(t)=1$ for $t\in[T_2,T_3)$. Generally, $X(t)=1$ for every inter-arrival time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the total law of probability we have for any $t>0$ that $$P(X(t)=0)=pP(X(t)=0|X(0)=0)+(1-p)P(X(t)=0|X(0)=1)$$ Again by the total law the probability $P(X(t)=0|X(0)=0)$ equals the sum $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}P(X(t)=0|X(0)=0,N(t)=k)P(N(t)=k|X(0)=0)$$ Note $P(X(t)=0|X(0)=0,N(t)=k)$ equals $0$ when $k$ is odd and $1$ when $k$ is even. With geometric series and the independence of $X(0)$ with $N(t)$ we have $$P(X(t)=0|X(0)=0)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}P(N(t)=2k|X(0)=0)=\frac{\mu t +1}{2\mu t +1}$$ A symmetric argument produces $$P(X(t)=0|X(0)=1)=\frac{1}{2\mu t +1}$$ Putting everything together, $$P(X(t)=0)=\frac{p \mu t}{2\mu t +1}$$ It's now easy to see that $X(t) \sim \text{Bernoulli}\Bigg(\frac{(2-p)\mu t +1}{2\mu t +1}\Bigg)$

Comment: Thank you for the derivation! Why is $P(X(t)=0|X(0)=0,N(t)=k)=0$ when $k$ is odd?  I do not understand how it is related to that the probability an arrival occurs in a particular time is zero.

Comment: The event that $N(t)=k$ means there were exactly $k$ arrivals in $[0,t]$. There is no way for $X(t)$ to equal $0$ if there is an odd number of arrivals in $[0,t]$ and $X(0)$ initially equals $0$. In fact this always the case, and will happen even if the $k^{th}$ arrival comes exactly at time $t$. I will edit my response accordingly.

Comment: Here I'm assuming $X(t)$ switches from $0$ to $1$ or from $1$ to $0$ at the exact moment of arrival.

Comment: Still a bit confused about this point. Let $t=1$, and $k=1$, $X(0)=0$ and the arrival occurs at $t=0.5$. In this case, $X(1)=0$ because no arrival at $t=1$, but an odd number of arrivals in $[0,1]$, $N(1)=1$.

Comment: The probability that an arrival occurs *exactly* at $t=1$ equals zero. If $X(t)$ alternates from $0$ to $1$ as you describe then $X(1)=0$ with probability $1$. I'm assuming that $ X(t)$ alternates between $0$ and $1$ in between arrivals.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!